# Are there really some wars about werewolfs?

Tags: twilight, werewolf

After having a look at *Twilight*, is there really any book relating where vampires lose to werewolves in a war? I have searched a lot but every result gives me answer that werewolves are creatures with hair.

Is there any book; a fiction book which explain some kind of even saga or a single story about werewolves in which vampires really do lose in a war with them?

Comment: This is requesting a list of recommended works, which IMO makes it off topic. VTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the *Twilight* saga? Book #2, *New Moon* talks about the [Quiluete's history](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Quileute_tribe), they talk about how they first met the vampires and in that story, the tribe wins.

Comment: Yeah I have read that, twilight according to me is a story book for children 10-. Above 10 or more the story is like a joke. I was asking for something outside. Something new.